# PostgreSQL could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)

Tags: postgresql, server, database-connection, psql, pgadmin

I tried to establish a connection in pgAdmin to the PostgresSQL server.
I always get the message:

```
could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053).
```

I read several posts where people had the same problem but they didn't help me.

Because my version was a bit older I uninstalled the whole postgresql and installed the newest version with the installer of EnterpriseDB (PostgreSQL 9.6 on windows 64). Everything looks fine. But I can't connect to the server from pgAdmin 4 again. I get the same error message.

```
In the logfile is written: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
```

Has anybody a clue what the problem could be?

Comment: The newest logfile says: 
- Datenbanksystem wurde am 2017-05-05 13:42:42 CEST heruntergefahren          
- MultiXact-Member-Wraparound-Schutz ist jetzt aktiviert              
- Datenbanksystem ist bereit, um Verbindungen anzunehmen                
- Autovacuum-Launcher startet                             
- konnte neue Verbindung nicht akzeptieren: Invalid argument

Comment: Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution for me was to restart the postgresql-server each time after booting up my computer with NET STOP and NET START. This was cumbersome but worked. 
Because my computer still had other connection problems, subsequently I updated my system to Windows 10 which totally solved all my problems.