# PgAdmin fatal error. The appllication server could not be contacted

Tags: windows-7, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

A couple of days before I have installed on my PC with Windows 7 Professional new version of PgAdmin (version 4). It worked fine, but today it loads slowly and then information window appears with text: "PgAdmin fatal error. The appllication server could not be contacted.". I restarted windows, but it doesn't help. Is there any solution of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that server is on local computer?

Comment: I had changed nothing.

Comment: The same thing happened to me using pgAdmin 4 (2.7.13). I had to reinstall it before it worked again.

Comment: Thanks. I reinstall it too and now it (still) works.

Comment: Hurrah! Solvation is to odify config_local.py file in web folder, adding  SERVER_MODE = False.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083391/postgresql-cant-connect-application-server-through-pgadmin4 For more info.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Try right clicking the PgAdmin icon and clicking "Run as administrator". Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

worked for me if I run PgAdmin as administrator.

Right click on the .exe file and run as administrator. It will work.

Comment: What does this add to the answer from last year saying the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

I tried all options mentioned in link [Postgresql can't connect application server through PGAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083391/postgresql-cant-connect-application-server-through-pgadmin4) .

But none of the options worked, then launching `C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v2\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe` from command prompt  worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

i got this error using PgAdmin 4 (v4.3) and here is what fixed it for me

1. right lick on my server and `disconnect server`
2. reconnect by clicking expand arrow on the server.

seems my connection was stale

Comment: This also helped fix "Software caused connection abort" [from your other (deleted) answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802310/postgresql-could-not-receive-data-from-server-software-caused-connection-abort)

Answer (score 2):

1. in C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
   delete folder pgAdmin
   (AppData - is hidden folder)
2. run pgadmin with administrator.

Worked Fine for me
Previously it was showing Fatal error

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall it, as Steve suggested in comments.  Then it started working again.

It's probably best to start with Ray Jowa's solution -- try right clicking the PgAdmin icon and clicking "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

This was odd, my PATH variable which had the python interpreter in it was somehow a factor, I do not completely understand though, right after I removed it everything worked, I will look further into it but so far I think that if you have python interpreter it might be the one causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

rename your C:\Users<your username>\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin to .back and restart pgAdmin v4.6x